# Grid layout - is this possible using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, flexbox

I'm currently using the following grid-layout:

```
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns: 400px 100px max-content 1fr 50px;
-ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr;
```

Which resembles this layout:

```
| <----------------- this has a fixed width --------------------------> |

+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|<- fix -> |<- fix -> | <--- growing ---> | <- shrinking -> | <- fix -> |
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|          |          | max-width content |                 |           |
+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Now, to be a bit more browser-supportig I could either use a [polyfill](https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill) or switch to flexbox layout (which is supported in most modern browsers).
Is the above layout possible to do using flexbox?

Comment: You _are_ using flexbox already – just only the `-ms-` prefixed version for IE only.

Comment: @CBroe: I was under the impression that FlexBox was defined using `display: flex;` and not `display: [-ms-]grid;` ?

Comment: You’re right, my bad.

Comment: ok, I've done a one-line demo at http://codepen.io/nils-a/pen/kKIEm - is this possible using 2 lines?

Comment: By 2 lines I assume you mean that they grow/shrink together, even if content only grows in one?

Comment: @MurraySmith: Exactly, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this short:
It is imposible to create a layout based on the `flexbox` layout-model which has more than one row and equal-sized "columns" if one or more of the cells have a dynaic width.